# Is There a Way to Specify in an S3 Policy That There Cannot Be an Empty String?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a policy that looks like:

```
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""]
```

Per the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-ConditionMatching):

> To configure the POST policy to allow any content within a form field, use starts-with with an empty value (""). This example allows any value for success_action_redirect:
>   `["starts-with", "$success_action_redirect", ""]`

The problem is you can send an empty string up and this will pass.
Is there a way to configure the policy so that it has to be x length or at least not an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't, but...

The option you have is to enforce the validation in your application, set the value in the form as a `hidden` field, and then include a `["eq", "$x-amz-meta-tag", "the same string you embedded in the form"]` condition in your policy.  Since the policy that is signed actually includes the required value, a user can't modify that value and submit the form without a policy violation occurring, denying the upload.

Comment: That's a smart way of going about it!

Comment: Oops, I put `starts-with` when I should have said `eq`.  Fixed.